# How to put a variable inside of a variable in python

Tags: python

I want to use a do something like:

```
i = 3

stored_number_i
```

Where `i` is 3

Is there a way to do this, or is it impossible? Is there at least a decent alternative?

Comment: Is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to create a `class` ? or store the variable in to a text file? store where?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want this; and there are often some good reasons to NOT want this kind of thing. Can your problem be solved with a list?

Comment: Usually, if you're looking for a way to access the name of a variable directly, you're having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323) that should be solved with a dictionary or a list. Please, as asked by @BurhanKhalid, describe your actual use case.

Comment: While this is possible, you should strongly consider using a `list` or `dict`. I've only ever found programmatic variables (or code) useful when it was generated using an explicit pattern, e.g. back when there was no `enum` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a `dict`.

```
stored_number = {23: 1, 1: 17, 3: 42}
print(stored_number[i])
```

prints `42` when `i` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt way to do this. You may find it useful to create your own datatype; namely a class.

That way, you can design the way data is stored in your "variable".

Answer (score 0):

Make a dummy class via

```
class dummy():
  pass
```

Then you can do `a=dummy()` to create your new object.

To set attributes you can either do `a.blarg=4` or `setattr(a,'blarg',4)`
This then gives you the possibility of doing something like you describe:

```
i=3
setattr(a,'stored_number_{0}'.format(i), 4)
```

which will give

```
a.stored_number_3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can do so in two ways:

- You can directly modify the `globals` dictionary, which holds all global variables of a module:

  ```
  globals()['stored_number_%s' % i] = "content of my programmatically created variable"
  ```
- You can `exec` the assignment, i.e. write the assignment code programmatically.

  ```
  exec('stored_number_%s = "content of my programmatically created variable"' % i)
  ```

Note that I've <strike>never</strike> rarely seen a usecase where this is appropriate to do. Usually, a `dict` or `list` is the correct data structure to use, where you can simply do `stored_number[i]`.